# Remove text occurrences contained in a specified area with iText

Tags: java, itext

Is it possible to remove all text occurrences contained in a specified area(red color rectangle area) of ​​a pdf document Using iText?

[image]

Comment: it would probably be useful if you attached the actual PDF file too

Comment: The functionality you're asking for has just been added to the latest release (iText 5.5.4). Are you using that release?

Comment: Not sure if that's sufficient, but you could overlay a non-transparent white area over the red rectangle area, so as to hide anything below it. I've only used iText indirectly but this should be possible.

Comment: @geert3 Usually that is not sufficient: people can always remove that white rectangle and even if the rectangle is in place, you can still select text in Adobe Reader and copy/past it. There has been a huge scandal in the US a while ago due to the approach you suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look at the [RemoveContentInRectangle](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/parse/RemoveContentInRectangle) example.

Let's say we have the following page:

[image]

Now we want to remove all the text in the rectangle defined by the coordinates: `llx = 97, lly = 405, urx = 480, ury = 445]` (where `ll` stands for lower-left and `ur` stands for upper-right).

We can now use the following code:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();
    cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(97f, 405f, 480f, 445f), BaseColor.GRAY));
    PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper);
    cleaner.cleanUp();
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

As you see, we define a list of `PdfCleanUpLocation` objects. To this list, we add a `PdfCleanUpLocation` passing the page number, a `Rectangle` defining the area we want to clean up, and a color that will show the area where content has been removed.

We then pass this list of `PdfCleanUpLocation`s to the `PdfCleanUpProcessor` along with the `PdfStamper` instance. We invoke the `cleanUp()` method and when we close the `PdfStamper` instance, we get the following result:

[image]

You can inspect this file: you will no longer be able to select any text in the gray area. All the text inside that rectangle has been removed.

Note that this code sample will only work if you add the itext-xtra.jar to your CLASSPATH (itext-xtra is shipped with iText core). It will only work with versions equal to or higher than iText 5.5.4.

Comment: how to get the rectangle position whatever mentioned(i.e new Rectangle(97f, 405f, 480f, 445f)).

Comment: That's a different question. Post it as a different question, since that's not what you asked. Your question was answered.

Comment: finding rectangle co ordinates  for  particular text is  important to me please give a solution.

Comment: If it's that important, then it would be wise to post you *additional* question as a new question. Your current question is about *a specified area*, NOT about an area that remains to be determined. Please accept my answer. I am not responsible for the fact that your question was wrong.

Comment: Any way thanks i posted the question please refer bellow link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917177/getting-co-ordinates-of-selected-area-from-pdf-using-itext

Comment: you done really greate work.I tried this in VB.net but i am getting null reference exception.This problem is happening when i passed rectangle parameters to PdfCleanUpProcessor. need some help